# How to use session object (IAuthSession) in ServiceStack out of service class?

Tags: c#, servicestack, inversion-of-control

I would like to save userId to the database from repository (each table in system has id field).

I wonder how to get session object out of service class?

My only idea is to register session object to the IoC container from service constructor and resolve it when needed.

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

No you should never register a Users Session in the IOC, a Users Session is tied to the HTTP Request since it is identified by a [Users Session Cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) that are available on the incoming request.

Resolving or saving a Users Session requires access to the current request. Please see the Session docs on different ways to [access the current request outside of a Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#saving-outside-a-service).

Comment: Using TryGetCurrentRequest limits repositories to be used only from http requests. What if there is a timer based task which has user account "system" and it periodically makes changes to database. Repository must somehow get its "fake" (non-http) session.

Comment: @smokeing which is by expected, the session cookies on the incoming HTTP Request contains the session id, if you're not in the context of a request you don't have access the session Id unless you've stored it elsewhere. If you have stored the sessionId elsewhere you can use the Session Id to resolve the Session Key with `SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(sessionId)` and access it directly from the registered `ICacheClient` with `cache.Get<IAuthUserSession>(sessionKey)`.